# Image unsupported when using intent to view image in gallery

Tags: android, uri

I want to open an image stored in local storage in the gallery from my app. But it always shows that the image is unsupported.

Here is the code:

```
File fileStr = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Storifier/test.jpg");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", fileStr);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpg");
startActivity(intent);
```

The Uri that I get for the file is

```
content://com.purple.myapplication.provider/external_files/Storifier/test.jpg
```

The image is stored in Storifier folder in the storage

I am a newbie!

Comment: Add something like `intent.setExtra(EXTRA_STREAM, uri);`.

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work mate

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Comment: Oh this worked. thanks a lot. I was using setFlags instead of addFlags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

add this in your activity result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                image_view.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

and add this in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```